# Java collection aggregate using lambdas

Tags: java, collections, lambda

I am new to java 8 lamdas. I need help on the below collection aggregation and sorted list.
I have Arraylist of object which has List

```
[
[parentName1,parentkey1, child1Name1, childKey1],
[parentName1,parentkey1, child1Name2, childKey2],
[parentName3,parentkey3, child1Name3, childKey3],
[parentName3,parentkey3, child1Name4, childKey4],
[parentName5,parentkey5, child1Name5, childKey5],
[parentName5,parentkey5, child1Name6, childKey6]
]
```

I would like aggregate above collections using java 8 lambdas in to sorted list.

```
List(Parent(parentName1,parentkey1,  List(  Child(child1Name1,childKey1),Child(child1Name2, childKey2)  ),
     Parent(parentName3,parentkey3,  List(  Child(child1Name3,childKey3),Child(child1Name4, childKey4)  ),
     Parent(parentName5,parentkey5,  List(  Child(child1Name5,childKey5),Child(child1Name5, childKey6)  )
     );
```

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand sorting criteria using which you wanted to sort the list but here is generic example but with little modification it ll work for your case also.

```
  employeeList.stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getEmployeeNumber(), e2.getEmployeeNumber()))
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Above example shows examplyee object can be sorted based employee number, but you can change the logic to fit your case.